# Bash - Counting substrings in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am kinda struggling to write a command which counts how many times a sub-string appears in a string.

Instead of running the code below 10 times, I would rather previously count how many times the sub-string appears and adapt the "for" based on its result:

Here you can see the code:

```
CommandResult="Interface    Chipset     Driver     mon0    Unknown      iwlwifi - [phy0]wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]"

for i in `seq 0 9`;
do
  InstanceID="mon"$i

  if echo "$CommandResult" | grep -q "$InstanceID"; then
    echo "found"
  fi
done
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Feel free to try this to get the number:

```
echo "$CommandResult" | tr " " "\n" | grep -c "$InstanceID"
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus. Thanks for your answer. How do I capture the result into a variable? I tried: NumberOfMatches="$CommandResult" | tr " " "\n" | grep -c "$searchString" But it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: `NumberOfMatches=$(echo "$CommandResult" | tr " " "\n" | grep -c "$InstanceID")`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `grep -o` to extract the desired string from the output:

```
#!/bin/bash
CommandResult="Interface    Chipset     Driver     mon0    Unknown      iwlwifi - [phy0]wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
Interface    Chipset     Driver     mon12    Unknown      iwlwifi - [phy0]wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]"

for InstanceId in $(grep -o 'mon[0-9]\+' <<< "$CommandResult") ; do
    echo "found $InstanceId "$(grep -c "$InstanceId" <<< "$CommandResult")' times'
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to share another solution. 3,5 years later, but better late than never I guess. ;)

I was working on a script that had to do the same, that is get the number of substrings in a string, and I was using `count=$(echo '$string' | grep -o ... | wc -l)` at first.
I got what I wanted, but when looping through ~1500 files with 0...8000 lines in each the performance was just terrible: the script took about *49 minutes* to complete.
So, I went and searched for alternative approaches and eventually found this:

```
InstanceId="mon0";
tmp="${CommandResult//$InstanceId}"
count=$(((${#CommandResult} - ${#tmp}) / ${#InstanceId}))
```

Got the same result but waaaay quicker, in 8-9 minutes.

### Explained:

```
tmp="${CommandResult//$InstanceId}"
```

This removes all occurrences of `$InstanceId` from `$CommandResult` and places it in `tmp`.
Actually we're using substring replacement here with replacement string missing. Syntax for substring replacement is `${string//substring/replacement}` (this replaces all occurrences of substring with replacement).

```
count=$(((${#CommandResult} - ${#tmp}) / ${#InstanceId}))
```

This gives us the number of occurrences of `$InstanceId` in `$CommandResult`.
`${#string}` gives string length so `(${#CommandResult} - ${#tmp])` is length of all occurrences of `$InstanceId` (remember, we removed all occurrences of `$InstanceId` from `$CommandResult` and placed the result in `$tmp`).
Then we just divide the substraction with length of `$InstanceId` to get the number of `$InstanceId` occurrences.

For further info about substring replacement and string length, see e.g. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html.

Comment: Incorrect brackets in count= line - but after changing, still could not get this to work with bash 4.3

Comment: Oh indeed, had some major typos there. Also incorrect use of quotes. Fixed the line and tested with bash 4.3.11(1)

Comment: I experienced the opposite. Searching and counting a string in 1000 files needed 33 seconds in pure bash, 7 seconds with `grep -o` and 4 seconds with `grep -oF`.

Comment: @mgutt that's interesting. I wonder if tools have evolved in 5 years or if underlying HW / system setup affects this. When writing the answer I was using Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) running in VirtualBox on Windows host, and everything in HDD...

Comment: I think I figured out why my results differ from mgutt's: in my case I can't `grep -oF`and `wc -l` each file. I need to find if there are _less than_ X occurrences of a substring in a line so I can tell if something's missing: the files contain, among other data, list of USB vendor ID's found at given time, and I'm searching if some USB device has dropped at any point. So I'm looping over files, grepping certain string from each file (the vendor list is prefixed with a special string to distinguish it) and then looping over these grep results to check if there's too few vendor ID's present.

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CommandResult="Interface    Chipset     Driver     mon0    Unknown      iwlwifi - [phy0]wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]"
InstanceId="mon0";
count=`grep -o "$InstanceId" <<< "$CommandResult" | wc -l`
echo "$InstanceId encountered "$count" times";
```

The above would produce an output like this:

> mon0 encountered 1 times

The above could easily be expanded to take take a string as input:

```
#!/bin/bash
CommandResult=$1
InstanceId="mon0";
count=`grep -o "$InstanceId" <<< "$CommandResult" | wc -l`
echo "$InstanceId encountered "$count" times";
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
./script.sh "Interface chipset mon0 mon0 unknown .   test"
```

or perhaps send the output from another command as an argument:

```
./script.sh `cat file.txt`
```

of course `xargs` would also work:

```
cat script.txt | xargs ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
mon_num=$(airmon-ng | grep -Poc '\bmon\d+\b')
echo here are $mon_num mon interfaces

for m in $(airmon-ng | grep -Po '\bmon\d+\b')
do
        #do something
        echo "this is $m"
done
```

for the `airmon-ng` output such:

```
Interface   Chipset     Driver

mon0        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
mon1        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
mon2        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
```

will print

```
here are 3 mon interfaces
this is mon0
this is mon1
this is mon2
```